# C++11 without sequence point?

Tags: c++, c++11, deprecated, sequence-points

Wikipedia says that sequence points are deprecated in C++11. What does that mean? Does that mean that undefined behaviors due to sequence points has no effects?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the cited Wikipedia article?

Comment: @Péter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x

Answer (score 10):

One major problem with the term "sequence point" is that it suggests a type of absolute sequencing which never existed.  Consider the expression `a = (b(),c()) + d();`  There is a sequence point between `b()` and `c()`, but that doesn't mean everything else can be described as being clearly before `c()` or being clearly after `b()`.  It would be possible for `b()`, `c()`, and `d()`, to be evaludated in the order `bcd`, `bdc`, or `dbc`.  The "sequence" point terminology didn't really make that clear, but the newer terminology does.

Answer (score 9):

The term "sequence point" is deprecated in order to provide a clearer explanation. The C++ language should not change.

You can find more information [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/update-on-the-c-0x-language-standard/)

Comment: The link is broken. Probably it's moved here:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/update-on-the-c-0x-language-standard/

Comment: @Ryoji Thank you! I have updated the link.

Answer (score 8):

The phrase "sequence point" has been deprecated in favor of more explicit phrasing like "sequenced before". Sequence points were difficult to understand already. Adding multithreading make them almost impossible for anybody to deal with, so they were (at least mostly) eliminated in favor of other wording.